# Is there an open source library for testing CloudwatchLog Filters?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

**Goal**: Test CloudwatchLog Filters offline programatically. Ideally, would like to write a simple program to test many filters on many messages programatically. Something callable like : aws.cloudwatchLogsTester.isMatch(msg, filter)

**Problem**: Doesn't seem to be a resource available (e.g. npm package, py wheel, etc) that I can leverage to test filters on any given message. Ideally, don't want to re-implement what the documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html) says should happen.

Answer (score 2):

AWS API has the method *test-metric-filter* which is used to tests the filter pattern of a metric filter against a sample of log event messages.

So you should use it on the corresponding AWS SDK. For example, in python (package boto3) the code would be something like:

```py
import boto3

client = boto3.client('logs')
response = client.test_metric_filter(
    filterPattern='string',
    logEventMessages=[
        'string',
    ]
)
```

Documentation:

- [API Reference TestMetricFilter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_TestMetricFilter.html)
- [Boto3 test_metric_filter](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/logs.html#CloudWatchLogs.Client.test_metric_filter)

Comment: While not fulfilling the offline request, this is the best approach to get confirmation what you're doing works.

Comment: Right as @Maurice mentioned, I am specifically looking for an offline solution. For example, a library, or a docker image, etc.